# rotate sprite and shooting bullets from the end of a cannon

Tags: java, android, sprites, rotation, andengine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Align Gun with Bullets](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/33173/how-to-align-gun-with-bullets)

Hi all i have a problem in my Andengine code,

I need , when I touch the screen, shoot a bullet from the cannon (in the same direction of the cannon)
The cannon rotates perfectly but when I touch the screen the bullet is not created at the end of the turret

This is my code:

```
private void shootProjectile(final float pX, final float pY){
    int offX = (int) (pX-canon.getSceneCenterCoordinates()[0]);
    int offY = (int) (pY-canon.getSceneCenterCoordinates()[1]);
    if (offX <= 0)
            return ;
    if(offY>=0)
                    return;

    double X=canon.getX()+canon.getWidth()*0,5;
    double Y=canon.getY()+canon.getHeight()*0,5 ;
    final Sprite projectile;
    projectile = new Sprite( (float) X, (float) Y,
                    mProjectileTextureRegion,this.getVertexBufferObjectManager() );

    mMainScene.attachChild(projectile);


    int realX = (int) (mCamera.getWidth()+ projectile.getWidth()/2.0f);
    float ratio = (float) offY / (float) offX;
    int realY = (int) ((realX*ratio) + projectile.getY());

    int offRealX = (int) (realX- projectile.getX());
    int offRealY = (int) (realY- projectile.getY());
    float length = (float) Math.sqrt((offRealX*offRealX)+(offRealY*offRealY));
    float velocity = (float) 480.0f/1.0f;
    float realMoveDuration = length/velocity;

    MoveModifier modifier = new MoveModifier(realMoveDuration,projectile.getX(), realX, projectile.getY(), realY);
    projectile.registerEntityModifier(modifier);
}

@Override
public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {

    if (pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE){

        double  dx = pSceneTouchEvent.getX() -  canon.getSceneCenterCoordinates()[0];
        double  dy = pSceneTouchEvent.getY() -  canon.getSceneCenterCoordinates()[1];

        double  Radius = Math.atan2(dy,dx);
        double Angle = Radius * 180 / Math.PI;
        canon.setRotation((float)Angle);

        return  true;

    }
    else if (pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

        final float touchX = pSceneTouchEvent.getX();
        final float touchY = pSceneTouchEvent.getY();

        double  dx = pSceneTouchEvent.getX() -  canon.getSceneCenterCoordinates()[0];
        double  dy = pSceneTouchEvent.getY() -  canon.getSceneCenterCoordinates()[1];

        double  Radius = Math.atan2(dy,dx);
        double Angle = Radius * 180 / Math.PI;

        canon.setRotation((float)Angle);
        shootProjectile(touchX, touchY);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Anyone know how to calculate the coordinates (X,Y) of the end of the barrel to draw the bullet?

Answer (score 1):

If the base (point of rotation) of the cannon is `(CannonBaseX, CannonBaseY)`, and the length of the cannon barrel is `Radius`, then:

```
BulletX = CannonBaseX + Radius * Cos(Angle);
BulletY = CannonBaseY + Radius * Sin(Angle);
```

This may vary a bit depending on your coordinate system; it assumes an angle of 0 is pointing straight to the right, and that positive angles proceed counterclockwise, and that (0,0) is the upper left corner of the screen.  If you have a different system, you may need to transform the parameters somewhat.

Comment: Isnt that the same answer as in the other question Linked above

Comment: thanks for you answer but i tryed your solution and the bulled is creates in diferents parts of the screen and not  in de end of barrel :(

see the modifications:
[syntax="java"]

  int x2 = (int) (canon.getSceneCenterCoordinates()[0]+LENGTH_SPRITE*Math.cos(canon.getRotation()));
  int y2 = (int) (canon.getSceneCenterCoordinates()[1]+LENGTH_SPRITE*Math.sin(canon.getRotation()));

  final Sprite projectile; 
  projectile = new Sprite( (float) x2, (float) y2,
    mProjectileTextureRegion,this.getVertexBufferObjectManager() );

[/syntax]
any idea? thx again.